# Remove white spaces in a single column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet that I need to remove the spaces from so I can compare it I am using a function I found on here and a sub that puts all the values into an array (for speed) but I cannot get it to work any idea why. I get a

> ByRef argument type mismatch error

```
Public Function RemoveWhiteSpace(target As String) As String
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "\s"
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        RemoveWhiteSpace = .Replace(target, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function


Sub stringRangeToClean()

Dim r As Variant
Dim i As Long

r = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trent BASE DATA").UsedRange

For i = 2 To UBound(r)

        r(i, 10).Value2 = RemoveWhiteSpace(r(i, 10))

Next i

End Sub
```

now trying this have I realised the col I is actually (I,9)
but im getting an error user defined type error on the RegExp line

```
Public Function RemoveWhiteSpace(target As String) As String

    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "\s"
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        RemoveWhiteSpace = .Replace(target, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function

Sub stringRangeToClean()

Dim r As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim txt As String


r = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trent BASE DATA").UsedRange

For i = 2 To UBound(r)

       txt = r(i, 9)
       txt = RemoveWhiteSpace(txt)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: where have the comments gone?

Comment: You're just removing spaces? This can be done with a single line of code: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trent BASE DATA").Cells.Replace " ", vbNullString`

Comment: no I only want to remove spaces in column (I, 10) or column I but only if there is a value in there hence why I have used the .usedRange and used a loop to go down the sheet and look at the offset (0,10) of the range

Comment: Then instead of `.Cells` change that portion to `.Range("J:J")`.  And if there's not a value in the cell, it won't change anyway so no need to try to exclude those, it won't add any time.

Comment: I know the .value2 is wrong but it doesn't work with the .value2 removed

Comment: I also don't want to include the header I2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go, no regex required for simply removing spaces.  Your main challenge is just defining your range which is basic VBA:

```
Sub tgr()

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trent BASE DATA")
        .Range("J2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)).Replace " ", vbNullString
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I think in this way if I have a blank cell half way up it will stop

Comment: Did you actually try it? You should try it.

Comment: yes it works now ive selected the right column thanks

Comment: I like this code just out of interest is there a way to reverse this once I have finished to make the original data readable

Comment: You'd need to store the original data in an array, or copy it to another column before removing the white spaces.

Comment: I think this what I need to do would use the array approach. unless I can compare the data to another cell which is what im doing but make it not compare the number or position of spaces

Comment: It sounds like you have another goal here.  If your actual goal is simply to compare cells while ignoring spaces, use the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) like so: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")=SUBSTITUTE(B1," ","")`

Comment: And if you do actually have a different goal than what you've asked, that is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Always start with your intended goal, or you'll get wayward answers.

Comment: Has not changed I'm just looking at a different approach do I remove or substitute that's all thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
Public Function RemoveWhiteSpace(target As String) As String

    Dim RegExp    As Object
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With RegExp
        .Pattern = "\s"
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        RemoveWhiteSpace = .Replace(target, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```

This way you are using a **late binding** for the `regExp` variable, thus neither you nor your users have to add any additional library.

If you want to use the **early binding**, you should add the `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"` library to the ones, that VBA uses. The early binding gives you some time bonus and it provides `IntelliSense`.

---

Here the selected answer explains step-by-step how to add the library:

[How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

---

Concerning your code - this is very simply loop, try to do it:

```
Sub StringRangeToClean()

    Dim r           As Variant
    Dim myCell      As Range

    r = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trent BASE DATA").UsedRange        
    For Each myCell In r
        myCell = RemoveWhiteSpace(txt)
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

This way every cell would be examined and the white spaces would be removed.

Comment: this has fixed my regEx error but it is not removing spaces

Comment: I only want to remove spaces in column J

Comment: then `R` should be something like this = `Intersect(Worksheets("Trent BASE DATA").UsedRange,Worksheets("Trent BASE DATA").columns("J"))`. But then you should check whether it is Not Nothing, in case that Column `J` is empty.

Comment: heres another related question instead of removing can I compare each cell to another cell but ignore spaces, so that only characters are been compared not the number or position of spaces